# Function to normalize any number from 0 - 1

Tags: javascript, performance, math, normalization

I'm trying to make a function that takes a number and normalizes it from 0 - 1 between its min and max bounds. For example:

If I want to normalize a value of 10 between 5 to 15, I call this:

`val = 10; normalize(val, 5, 15);`  Returns 0.5

normalizing a value 0 between -10 and 5

`val = 0; normalize(val, -10, 5);`  Returns 0.666

This is the function I came up with:

```
function normalize(val, min, max){
  // Shift to positive to avoid issues when crossing the 0 line
  if(min < 0){
    max += 0 - min;
    val += 0 - min;
    min = 0;
  }
  // Shift values from 0 - max
  val = val - min;
  max = max - min;
  return Math.max(0, Math.min(1, val / max));
}
```

My question is: Is this the most efficient method to normalize a 1-dimensional value? I'm going to be calling this function a few thousand times per frame at 60fps, so I'd like to have it as optimized as possible to reduce the burden of calculation. I've looked for normalization formulas, but all I find are 2- or 3-dimensional solutions.

Comment: I don't see the reason why you are treating negative mins separately,

Comment: is min and max always the same for the array?

Comment: @redneb Wow, you're right! I was preemptively doing so without really testing it. It works without shifting to > 0

Comment: @NinaScholz min and max would change depending on where I'm calling it. Sometimes it'll be `-100, 0` sometimes `-3, 781`, etc.

Comment: @MarcoDelValle So just remove the special handling of negative min and you are good to go.

Comment: Micro optimization should not be your concern.  norm - (x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin) is sufficient.  You assume that xmin <= x <= xmax in every case.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Why not just:

```js
(val, max, min) => (val - min) / (max - min);
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! This seems to be the simplest way. I was overcomplicating things with the if statement. However, I still want to clamp the values between 0 and 1, so I'm thinking of doing `return Math.max(0, Math.min(1, val-min / max-min))`

Comment: @MarcoDelValle As long as `val` is actually between `min` and `max` the result will always be between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Keiwan I know. The thing is that `val` won't always be between `min` and `max`, so I need a way to keep it from returning negative numbers or anything above 1

Comment: @MarcoDelValle: Don't forget to put parentheses around `(max-min)`.

Comment: @Keiwan what if I want value between -1, 1

Comment: @HassanAnsari is a little to late for you I asume, but for others what will search for this answer, the math is simple. You need to multiply the vale by 2 and than subtract 1. e.g.: `function(val, max, min) { return (val - min) / (max - min) * 2 - 1; }`

Comment: If val > max , this always returns 1. Is that what OP wanted?

Answer (score 19):

Using [Nathan Bertons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39776893/1447675)'s answer with a preconfigured function for some values with the same `min` and `max` values, you could use this.

```js
function normalize(min, max) {
    var delta = max - min;
    return function (val) {
        return (val - min) / delta;
    };
}

console.log([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15].map(normalize(5, 15)));
```

Answer (score 9):

I prefer using this formula when I want to normalize a value between two ranges with known min, max values. You can add checks to constrain the input, although this will correctly calculate the difference from the new range if an out-of-range value is given as input.

```js
/**
 * Normalizes a value from one range (current) to another (new).
 *
 * @param  { Number } val    //the current value (part of the current range).
 * @param  { Number } minVal //the min value of the current value range.
 * @param  { Number } maxVal //the max value of the current value range.
 * @param  { Number } newMin //the min value of the new value range.
 * @param  { Number } newMax //the max value of the new value range.
 *
 * @returns { Number } the normalized value.
 */
const normalizeBetweenTwoRanges = (val, minVal, maxVal, newMin, newMax) => {
  return newMin + (val - minVal) * (newMax - newMin) / (maxVal - minVal);
};

const e = document.getElementById('result');
e.innerHTML = normalizeBetweenTwoRanges(10, 5, 15, 0, 1);
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Just be careful as this won't support negative ranges, here's an implementation that does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51161208/930675 sorry it's in C#.

Answer (score 6):

Using [Nathan Bertons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39776893/1447675)'s answer, you must validate if max-min is equal to zero, otherwise the return will be NaN:

```
function (val, max, min) { 
    if(max - min === 0) return 1; // or 0, it's up to you
    return (val - min) / (max - min); 
}
```

and you can use a [generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)) to restrict the range of values in the dataset between any arbitrary points a and b using:

```
function (val, max, min) {
    if(max - min === 0) return a; // or b, it's up to you
    return a + (((val - min) * (b-a)) / (max - min));
}
```

Comment: `max - min` will equal to zero if they have same value, there's no way you would give `max = 5` and `min = 5`.

Answer (score 1):

I Will complete answer of Nina Scholz, you can use underscore library to find minimum and maximum for array and you can use as follow, or create your own (simple methods with simple loop):

if you are using nodeJS you need to install underscore with command npm install underscore and use with command
`var _ = require('underscore/underscore');`
or you can import the library on html and use on your web

```
    function min(arr) {
        if (!arr.length) return null;
        var minValue = arr[0];
        for (var item of arr) {
            if (item  maxValue) maxValue = item;
        }
        return maxValue;
    }

    var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    function normalize(min, max) {
        var delta = max - min;
        return function (val) {
            return (val - min) / delta;
        };
    }

    function normalizeArray(array) {
        var minValue = min(array); //if you use underscore _.min(array)
        var maxValue = max(array);//if you use underscore _.max(array)
        return array.map(normalize(minValue, maxValue));
    }
    console.log(normalizeArray(array));
```

Comment: Sorry here you find also the max function :)

   function max(arr) {
        if (!arr.length) return null;
        var maxValue = arr[0];
        for (var item of arr) {
            if (item > maxValue) maxValue = item;
      }
    return maxValue;
}

Answer (score 0):

With *max-min* limit

```
function normalize(min, max) {
   const delta = max - min;
   return val => ( (val < min? min: (val > max? max : val)) - min ) / delta;
}
console.log([-2,3,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,23].map(normalize(0, 10)));
// [
```

output: [0,
0.3,
0.5,
0.6,
0.7,
0.8,
0.9,
1,
1,
1
]

Comment: Simpler: `return Math.max(0, Math.min(1, val-min / max-min))`

Answer (score -1):

If you want a more dynamic approach, where you can specify the max range, then this can be the solution here, we in this example we are normalizing our data in a range of 0 to 100

```
    let a = [500, 2000, 3000, 10000];

    function normalize(data, arr_max, arr_min, newMax){
        return data.map(d => {
            return newMax * ((d - arr_min)/(arr_max - arr_min))
        })
    }


console.log(normalize(a, 10000, 500, 100))
```

Comment: I feel that this simply overcomplicates the accepted answer. I never asked for array mapping, nor multiplying by a `newMax` value.