# Normalize Range -100 to 100 to 0 to 3

Tags: c#, math

I have a number range `-100` to `100`.

I'm trying to Normalize it to `0` to `3` with decimal places.

```
-100 = 0
-50  = 0.75
 0   = 1.5
 50  = 2.25
 100 = 3
```

---

I want to create a program function to normalize any range to any value such as:

http://rextester.com/ZJWNS24313

```
double Normalize(double val, double valmin, double min, double max) 
{
    return (val - valmin) / (max - min);
}
```

However this does not give the correct output.

`100` becomes `66.6666666666667` instead of `3`.

---

If I multiply the formula by a decimal `0.045` it turns out correct.

`((100 - -100) / (3 - 0)) * 0.045` = `3`

`((50 - -100) / (3 - 0)) * 0.045` = `2.25`

`((-50 - -100) / (3 - 0)) * 0.045` = `0.75`

But how can the formula be made so I don't have to specify the decimal number at the end?

Because if I wanted to normalize a new number to `0` to `5` I would have to change it to `0.125`.

Comment: It seems like you're missing a parameter. You need the value to normalize, the current range for that value (min and max) and the normalized range (min and max).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
double Normalize(double val, double valmin, double valmax, double min, double max) 
{
    return (((val - valmin) / (valmax - valmin)) * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

(Assuming valmin and valmax are -100 to 100 and min and max are 0 to 3)

> Edit: should add the min value at the end not subtract

Comment: This seems to be working great, I'll test on several values and get back to you.

Comment: Should that be a '+' before the final term?

Comment: Yes @DarenW, I just saw that too