# Get a weighted value between 0 and 1 based on zero being min value and 1 max value

Tags: javascript, math

Let's set I have a set of numbers: `Set(6) { 0, 2.58, 2.74, 2.75, 4.12, 5.5 }`. These sum to `17.69`.

I know I can get a weighted / percentage based value between 0 and 1 by dividing each number by the total, which produces:

```js
{
  '0': 0,
  '2.58': 0.14584511023176935,
  '2.74': 0.15488976823063877,
  '2.75': 0.1554550593555681,
  '4.12': 0.2328999434708875,
  '5.5': 0.3109101187111362
}
```

The result I am looking for though, is more like this:

```js
{
  '0': 0,
  '2.58': around 0.5,
  '2.74': just over 0.5,
  '2.75': just over 0.5,
  '4.12': around 0.8,
  '5.5': 1
}
```

So the closer a number is to the higher number in the set, the closer to 1 it is.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

For context, I need to be able to show a faded color around the box containing these numbers so I'm looking for a value between 0 and 1 so that I can assign that to the opacity using CSS.

Comment: So you want `value / max`, and then round that up or down a bit ...?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it to be honest. If 5,5 is my largest number, that needs to be 1, if zero is my smallest number, that needs to be 0 and everything in the middle is scaled based on it's relativity to the min / max values ... Does that make sense?

Comment: _"If 5,5 is my largest number, that needs to be 1, if zero is my smallest number, that needs to be 0 "_ - that would be "already included", with `5.5/5.5` and `0/5.5`. Question is what your actual definition of _"scaled based on it's relativity to the min / max values"_ would be then, if _not_ the same thing for the values in between.

Comment: Something like this: [Function to normalize any number from 0 - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39776819)?

Comment: @001 That looks promising! Will take a look. Normalise is probably the word I was looking for.

Comment: @001 That was it! Thanks so much. Basically, this sorted it: `const normalise = (val, max, min) => (val - min) / (max - min)`

Comment: This works for me: `const normalise_array = (array) => { let min = Math.min(...array); let max = Math.max(...array); return array.map(n => (n - min) / (max - min)); }` Calling `normalise_array([0, 413, 1354])` returns `[0, 0.3050221565731167, 1]`

Comment: @001 Sorry, yes, I deleted my comment. My initial array was messed up a little so it did't get the proper max value to calc from. It's all working.

Answer (score 1):

```
mySet = new Set([0, 2.58, 2.74, 2.75, 4.12, 5.5]);
myArray = Array.from(mySet);
max = myArray.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (prev === null) {
    return curr;
  } else if (curr > prev) {
    return curr;
  } else {
    return prev;
  }
}, null);

resultAsArray = myArray.map(item => item/max);

resultsAsObject = myArray.reduce((prev, curr, i) => {
  return Object.assign(prev, {[curr]: resultAsArray[i]});
}, {})
```

If you want to handle numbers like `0.4982734923847` as shorter things,
you can do, for example, `{[curr]: resultAsArray[i].toFixed(2)}`

Comment: Not ideal to just dump a code solution into an answer. Worth adding some description of how you think this solves the problem and what the output is.

Answer (score 0):

For every element in your array:

- subtract min(input array)
- divide by (max(input array) - min(input array))
- round if you like.

E.g., inputs: [7,13, 17, 22]

- subtraction by 7 yields: [0, 6, 10, 15]
- division by 15 yields: [0, 6/15, 10/15, 15/15] = [0, 0.4, 0.666667, 1]