# How to convert decibel value i,e between -96 to 96

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Hi i'm facing a problem with respect to decibel convertion

**Question:** html5 volume accepted range is between 0 - 1  now how to convert decibel value i,e between -96 to 96 into 0-1.

Here is what i have tried:

```js
  function linearToDecibel(linearValue) {
      // Convert linear value to decibels
      var decibelValue = 20 * Math.log10(linearValue);
      return decibelValue;
   }

  console.log(linearToDecibel(96)) // my expection is value 1 or 100%
```

Further conversion i dont know please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function to normalize any number from 0 - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776819/function-to-normalize-any-number-from-0-1)

Comment: 0 dB is defined as the threshold of human hearing. Do you really want your scale to cover -96 through 0 dB?

Answer (score 3):

To convert -96 -> 96 on a range of 0 -> 1 you can

(x + 96) / (96 * 2)

And you can simplify by

(x + 96) / 192

Answer (score 3):

There is actually no standard definition of what "volume" means exactly, but a good assumption would be that it corresponds to signal *amplitude*.  Decibels are 10*log<sub>10</sub>(power), and power = amplitude<sup>2</sup>, so under that assumption:

dB = 10*log<sub>10</sub>(volume<sup>2</sup>) + C = `C + 20*Math.log10(volume)`

Note that when volume=0, i.e. in silence, db = -Infinity.  You'll have to map that to -96dB explicitly.

The `C` is a constant that comes from adding an arbitrary volume scaling factor and taking it out of the logarithm.  You have to choose this to define what max volume means in terms of dB.

Many systems that set volume in dB set `C = 0`.  This makes "0dB" the maximum possible volume without clipping, so all of the volume settings you actually use are negative dB values.  My stereo is usually set around -36db, for example.

If you want to be able to set volumes all the way up to 96dB, then `C=96.0`.  That will put all of the common volumes > 60, though, which is kind of weird.

You could set `C` so that 0dB comes out to the "threshold of hearing", but of course that is room specific and requires calibration.

If none of those options work for you, then pick `C` however you like.

---

Note that, while there are certainly a lot of systems that implement the above definition of volume = amplitude, it leads to volume controls that are too sensitive on the lower end.  My understanding from limited research is that *professional* systems generally try to make their volume controls more usable throughout most common volume ranges.

According to the [MIDI specification](http://www.shclemen.com/download/The%20Complete%20MIDI1.0%20Detailed%20Spec.pdf), MIDI equipment manufacturers have settled on the formula: `db = C + 40*Math.log10(volume)`, which corresponds to power = volume<sup>4</sup>, or amplitude = volume<sup>2</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

You can normalize the `value` based on the `fromRange`, and then scale it to the `toRange`.

```js
/**
 * Normalizes and scales a number from one range to another.
 * @param {number} value - value to scale
 * @param {number[]} fromRange - source range [min, max] (inclusive)
 * @param {number[]} toRange - target range [min, max] (inclusive)
 * @returns {number} A scaled value respective of the toRange
 */
const scaleValue = (value, fromRange, toRange) =>
  (value - fromRange[0]) *
  (toRange[1] - toRange[0]) /
  (fromRange[1] - fromRange[0]) +
  toRange[0];

/**
 * Convert a decibel value to a percentage.
 * @param {number} decibelVal - decibel value to scale to linear
 * @returns {number} A value between [0.0, 1.0]
 */
const decibelToLinear = (decibelVal) => scaleValue(decibelVal, [-96, 96], [0, 1]);

/**
 * Convert a percentage value to a decibel value.
 * @param {number} linearVal - linear value to scale to decibel
 * @returns {number} A value between [-95, 95]
 */
const linearToDecibel = (linearVal) => scaleValue(linearVal, [0, 1], [-96, 96]);

console.log(decibelToLinear(-96)); // 0.0  or    0%
console.log(decibelToLinear(0));   // 0.5  or   50%
console.log(decibelToLinear(96));  // 1.0  or  100%

console.log(linearToDecibel(0.0)); // -96
console.log(linearToDecibel(0.5)); //   0
console.log(linearToDecibel(1.0)); //  96
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a general linear transformation, you can create a function that will take a source range and a target range and return a function that accepts a number in the source range and returns its equivalent in the target.  This is very much the same technique Mr. Polywhirl uses, but with a slightly different API and a very different coding style:

```js
const scale = ([a, b], [c, d]) => (x) =>
  Math.min(d, Math.max(c, (x - a) * (d - c) / ((b - a) || 1) + c))

const decibelScale = scale([0, 1], [-96, 96])

console.log (decibelScale(0))    //=> -96
console.log (decibelScale(.326)) //=> -33.408
console.log (decibelScale(0.5))  //=> 0
console.log (decibelScale(0.75)) //=> 48
console.log (decibelScale(0.9))  //=> 76.8
console.log (decibelScale(1))    //=> 96
```

This uses `Math.max/min` to cut off the result to fall within the target range.  If you don't want that, just remove those two calls.  The `|| 1` is just a trick to avoid division by zero issues.